# ctx.CurrentItem undefined in new function

Tags: 2013, javascript, display-template, ctx

I am editing a item display template in SharePoint 2013. The following problem occurs:

`ctx.CurrentItem` becomes undefined in a custom function.

How can I solve this?

Here is a little code snippet:

```
 var p = getFollowers();
 console.log("")
 console.debug(ctx.CurrentItem);
 p.done(function(result) {
  console.debug(followers);
  console.debug(ctx);
 });
```

Comment: well it is a standard display template and then you use . var uname = ctx.CurrentItem.PreferredName; but on the begin of the display template there is a check if currentitem is not null. and currentitem becomes empty when entering the p.done function

Comment: Can you put below line and then check ctx. var ctx= new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl); Thanks
Bhism

Comment: i can try this but i don't think it will work. The problem isn't the ctx but the currenitem is empty

Comment: Every example uses ``ctx`` as the variable *inside* a function, but ``ctx`` is a **global** object and JavaScript passes Objects by **reference**. So when you hit your done function ``ctx`` is something completely different in the global scope. The way to fix this depends on your code, this snippet alone is not enough.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well your problem, but I think that you can try this:
AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function() {             
//your code here
            });

Answer (score 1):

We fought this for more than 5 hours and it turns out all we had to do was reboot all the sharepoint servers and the ctx.currentitem started returning all of the managed property mappings.